# How to specify what is included in the JSON response?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am getting information from an API using Python requests with the following code:

```
import json
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://api.oxoservices.eu/api/v1/startups?site=labs&startup_status=funded')

json_resp = json.loads(resp.text)


for company in json_resp['data']:

    
    print(json.dumps(company, indent=4))
    print()
    with open("test.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        # file.write(str(json_resp))
        json.dump(json_resp, file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

It extracts all needed information, and a lot of not needed information as well, which is my problem.

I get the output:

```
"data": [
    {
        "cover": null,
        "cover_id": null,
        "created_at": "2021-01-05T05:56:03.000000Z",
        "focus": {
            "color": "#25c9b6",
            "created_at": "2016-06-15T10:46:50.000000Z",
            "id": 15,
            "is_active": true,
            "name": "Financial Technologies",
            "updated_at": "2016-06-15T10:46:50.000000Z"
        },
        "focus_id": 15,
        "id": 1111,
        "irr": 0,
        "is_active": false,
        "name": "iconicchain",
        "photo": {
            "created_at": "2021-11-15T17:16:17.000000Z",
            "filename": "iconicchain.png",
            "id": "52b7c33f-c74c-4099-88cb-944b4047cf85",
            "mime": "image/png",
            "size": 14056,
            "type": "photo",
            "url": "/attachments/52b7c33f-c74c-4099-88cb-944b4047cf85"
        },
        "photo_id": "52b7c33f-c74c-4099-88cb-944b4047cf85",
        "raised_type": {
            "id": 3,
            "key": "seed",
            "name": "Seed"
        },
        "startup_investment_type": {
            "id": 1,
            "key": "none",
            "name": "Not seeking"
        },
        "startup_stage_id": 4,
        "startup_status": {
            "id": 5,
            "key": "funded",
            "name": "Funded"
        },
        "startup_valuation_basis": {
            "id": 3,
            "key": "next_funding_round",
            "name": "Next funding round"
        },
        "summary": "Compliance based on facts, not faith-delivering regulatory compliance automation solutions for the financial sector.",
        "video_id": null,
        "video_type_id": "1",
        "website": "https://www.iconicchain.com"
```

From the data I would only like to extract the website, which in this case would be https://www.iconicchain.com, and only the name iconchain at the top.

Comment: Are you asking at the API level (in which case we can't tell you, it depends on the API) or at the Python level (in which case it's just basic dictionary and list manipulation)?

Comment: Either, I had this problem previously as well where I manually had to delete all the unwanted parts for each company, which is what I am trying my best to avoid.

Comment: Well for the first you'd need to read the documentation of the relevant API to see if it offers any options for filtering or refining the data in the response. For the second it's just trivial Python operations on standard types, it's unclear what problem you had previously but a [mre] would illustrate that.

Comment: The problem I had previously is the problem I am facing currently. The JSON response contains lots of information that I do not need. I am trying to come up with a way to get rid of those bits of information, of course, I would prefer to not even request the unwanted info, but as a beginner I am open to suggestions on best practices when dealing with a situation as such.

Comment: Again we can't tell you whether not requesting that information is an option, **it depends on the API**. Beyond that any basic tutorial (see e.g. https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) will tell you how to work with lists and dictionaries. For a useful SO question we'd need a more specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you're using requests to pull data from a JSON api, you don't need to import json package as well, requests by itself will parse json just fine. You can do what you need with requests and pandas only:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://api.oxoservices.eu/api/v1/startups?site=labs&startup_status=funded')
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['data'])
df = df[['name', 'website']]
print(df)
```

This will return:

```
name    website
0   iconicchain https://www.iconicchain.com
1   Gloster Nyrt.   https://gloster.hu/
2   Vilhemp https://vilhemp.hu
3   HackRate    https://hckrt.com/
4   Commsignia  http://www.commsignia.com
5   BitNinja    https://bitninja.io
[...]
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you need to save the information to file, you can do it with pandas: df.to_csv('my_info.csv').